# KSQL - INSERT INTO a Stream yields no data

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm having problems with reading messages from a stream which is being populated using the `INSERT INTO` KSQL operation.

The steps I've followed are:

I have a stream `event_stream` which I created from a kafka topic.

```
CREATE STREAM event_stream (eventType varchar, eventTime varchar, 
sourceHostName varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='events', value_format='json');
```

`SELECT * FROM event_stream;` shows messages coming in correctly.

I want to send some of these messages to another topic in kafka, `output_events`, which I have already created.

I then create a second stream in KSQL:

```
CREATE STREAM output_stream (eventTime varchar, extraColumn varchar, 
sourceHostName varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='output_events', value_format='json');
```

Finally, I link the input to the output with the following:

```
INSERT INTO output_stream SELECT eventTime, 'Extra info' as extraColumn,    
sourceHostName FROM event_stream WHERE eventType = 'MatchingValue';
```

All of the above seem to complete without errors, however if I run 
`SELECT * FROM output_stream;` I get no data.  Why is this?

Running the SELECT part of the above query works fine, so I can see matching results are arriving on the topic.

Strangely, if I run `DESCRIBE EXTENDED output_stream` the message count does indicate that messages are reaching the stream:

```
Local runtime statistics                                                                        
------------------------                                                                        
messages-per-sec:      0.33   total-messages:        86     last-message: 11/9/18 1:15:43 PM UTC
 failed-messages:         0 failed-messages-per-sec:         0      last-failed:       n/a      
(Statistics of the local KSQL server interaction with the Kafka topic output_events)
```

I've also checked the ksql-server logs, but can't seen any errors there.

Comment: What version of Confluent Platform are you using?

Comment: This is on version 5.0.0

Comment: And what happens when you look at the topic: `PRINT 'output_events' from beginning;` ?

Comment: Printing output_events from the beginning gives no results, and neither does setting 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest'; then re-running the SELECT statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2146), through unintentional misuse of the `CREATE STREAM` in the wrong syntax. You're using the variant to 'register' a KSQL stream against an existing topic. For `INSERT INTO` to work it needs to be a `CREATE STREAM target AS SELECT` ("CSAS").

Let's work it through. Here I'm using [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/cos/docker-compose.yml) docker-compose for a test setup.

Populate some dummy data:

```
docker run --rm --interactive --network cos_default confluentinc/cp-kafkacat kafkacat -b kafka:29092 -t events -P <<EOF
{"eventType":"1", "eventTime" :"2018-11-13-06:34:57", "sourceHostName":"asgard"}
{"eventType":"2", "eventTime" :"2018-11-13-06:35:57", "sourceHostName":"asgard"}
{"eventType":"MatchingValue", "eventTime" :"2018-11-13-06:35:58", "sourceHostName":"asgard"}
EOF
```

Register the source topic with KSQL:

```
CREATE STREAM event_stream (eventType varchar, eventTime varchar, sourceHostName varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='events', value_format='json');
```

Query the stream:

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'null' to 'earliest'
ksql> SELECT * FROM event_stream;
1542091084660 | null | 1 | 2018-11-13-06:34:57 | asgard
1542091084660 | null | 2 | 2018-11-13-06:35:57 | asgard
1542091785207 | null | MatchingValue | 2018-11-13-06:35:58 | asgard
```

So looking at the `CREATE STREAM` that you quote:

```
CREATE STREAM output_stream (eventTime varchar, extraColumn varchar, sourceHostName varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='output_events', value_format='json');
```

My guess is that if you run `LIST TOPICS;` you'll see that this topic already exists on your Kafka broker?

```
ksql> LIST TOPICS;

Kafka Topic            | Registered | Partitions | Partition Replicas | Consumers | ConsumerGroups
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_confluent-metrics     | false      | 12         | 1                  | 0         | 0
_schemas               | false      | 1          | 1                  | 0         | 0
docker-connect-configs | false      | 1          | 1                  | 0         | 0
docker-connect-offsets | false      | 25         | 1                  | 0         | 0
docker-connect-status  | false      | 5          | 1                  | 0         | 0
events                 | true       | 1          | 1                  | 0         | 0
output_events          | false      | 4          | 1                  | 0         | 0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ksql>
```

Because if it wasn't, this `CREATE STREAM` would fail:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM output_stream (eventTime varchar, extraColumn varchar, sourceHostName varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='output_events', value_format='json');
Kafka topic does not exist: output_events
ksql>
```

So making this assumption I'm also creating this topic on my test cluster:

```
$ docker-compose exec kafka bash -c "kafka-topics --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4 --topic output_events"
```

And then creating the stream:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM output_stream (eventTime varchar, extraColumn varchar, sourceHostName varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='output_events', value_format='json');

Message
----------------
Stream created
----------------
```

Note that it says `Stream created`, rather than `Stream created and running`

Now let's run the `INSERT INTO`:

```
ksql> INSERT INTO output_stream SELECT eventTime, 'Extra info' as extraColumn, sourceHostName FROM event_stream WHERE eventType = 'MatchingValue';

Message
-------------------------------
Insert Into query is running.
-------------------------------
```

The `DESCRIBE EXTENDED` output does indeed show, as you have seen, messages being processed:

```
ksql> DESCRIBE EXTENDED output_stream;

Name                 : OUTPUT_STREAM
Type                 : STREAM
Key field            :
Key format           : STRING
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Value format         : JSON
Kafka topic          : output_events (partitions: 4, replication: 1)

Field          | Type
--------------------------------------------
ROWTIME        | BIGINT           (system)
ROWKEY         | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
EVENTTIME      | VARCHAR(STRING)
EXTRACOLUMN    | VARCHAR(STRING)
SOURCEHOSTNAME | VARCHAR(STRING)
--------------------------------------------

Queries that write into this STREAM
-----------------------------------
InsertQuery_0 : INSERT INTO output_stream SELECT eventTime, 'Extra info' as extraColumn, sourceHostName FROM event_stream WHERE eventType = 'MatchingValue';

For query topology and execution plan please run: EXPLAIN <QueryId>

Local runtime statistics
------------------------
messages-per-sec:      0.01   total-messages:         1     last-message: 11/13/18 6:49:46 AM UTC
failed-messages:         0 failed-messages-per-sec:         0      last-failed:       n/a
(Statistics of the local KSQL server interaction with the Kafka topic output_events)
```

But the topic itself has no messages:

```
ksql> print 'output_events' from beginning;
^C
```

nor the KSQL Stream:

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM OUTPUT_STREAM;
^CQuery terminated
```

---

So the `INSERT INTO` command is designed to run against *an existing CSAS/CTAS* target stream, rather than a *source STREAM registered against an existing topic.*

Let's try it that way instead. First, we need to drop the existing stream definition, and to do that also terminate the `INSERT INTO` query:

```
ksql> DROP STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM;
Cannot drop OUTPUT_STREAM.
The following queries read from this source: [].
The following queries write into this source: [InsertQuery_0].
You need to terminate them before dropping OUTPUT_STREAM.
ksql> TERMINATE InsertQuery_0;

Message
-------------------
Query terminated.
-------------------
ksql> DROP STREAM OUTPUT_STREAM;

Message
------------------------------------
Source OUTPUT_STREAM was dropped.
------------------------------------
```

Now create the target stream:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM output_stream WITH (kafka_topic='output_events') AS SELECT eventTime, 'Extra info' as extraColumn, sourceHostName FROM event_stream WHERE eventType = 'MatchingValue';

Message
----------------------------
Stream created and running
----------------------------
```

Note that in creating the stream it is also `running` (vs before it was just `created`). Now query the stream:

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM OUTPUT_STREAM;
1542091785207 | null | 2018-11-13-06:35:58 | Extra info | asgard
```

and check the underlying topic too:

```
ksql> PRINT 'output_events' FROM BEGINNING;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1542091785207,"ROWKEY":"null","EVENTTIME":"2018-11-13-06:35:58","EXTRACOLUMN":"Extra info","SOURCEHOSTNAME":"asgard"}
```

So, you have hit a bug in KSQL ([raised here](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2146)), but one that fortunately can be avoided by using a simpler KSQL syntax entirely, combining your `CREATE STREAM` and `INSERT INTO` queries into one.